# How do I make tidy data from rows of observations?

Tags: r, pivot, reshape

I want to make a ggplot boxplot and I think I need to format my data from this:

```
markerID        V1        V2        V3
       1 0.8636364 0.8409091 0.7954545
       2 0.8863636 0.8409091 0.8409091
```

to this:

```
markerID  replicate      rate
       1          1 0.8636364
       1          2 0.8409091
       1          3 0.7954545
       2          1 0.8863636
       2          2 0.8409091
       2          3 0.8409091
```

For readability I'm only showing part of the data.

I think once I have this format I can group by markerID and then make my boxplot. The number of columns and rows can vary, so I'm not sure how to apply functions like melt() or pivot_longer().

Example data:

```
structure(list(markerID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), V1 = c(0.863636363636364, 
0.886363636363636, 0.886363636363636, 0.795454545454545, 0.795454545454545, 
0.863636363636364, 0.931818181818182, 0.909090909090909, 0.840909090909091, 
0.863636363636364, 0.886363636363636, 0.795454545454545, 0.818181818181818, 
0.863636363636364, 0.886363636363636), V2 = c(0.840909090909091, 
0.840909090909091, 0.909090909090909, 0.772727272727273, 0.772727272727273, 
0.909090909090909, 0.886363636363636, 0.886363636363636, 0.954545454545455, 
0.75, 0.818181818181818, 0.772727272727273, 0.681818181818182, 
0.863636363636364, 0.840909090909091), V3 = c(0.795454545454545, 
0.840909090909091, 0.886363636363636, 0.818181818181818, 0.818181818181818, 
0.795454545454545, 0.818181818181818, 0.863636363636364, 0.818181818181818, 
0.818181818181818, 0.931818181818182, 0.772727272727273, 0.772727272727273, 
0.886363636363636, 0.886363636363636)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: `reshape2::melt(quux, id.vars="markerID", variable.name="replicate", variable.factor=FALSE, value.name="rate") |> transform(replicate = sub("^V", "", replicate))` (or `data.table::melt` if using that package and a `data.table` object) or `pivot_longer(quux, cols=-markerID, names_to="replicate", values_to="rate", names_prefix="V")` if using `dplyr`/`tidyr`.

Comment: After that, see https://r-graph-gallery.com/boxplot.html for examples, sample data, and code for generating various boxplot charts with `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach using `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, -markerID, names_prefix="V", names_to="replicate", values_to="rate")
# A tibble: 45 × 3
   markerID replicate  rate
   <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
 1 1        1         0.864
 2 1        2         0.841
 3 1        3         0.795
 4 2        1         0.886
 5 2        2         0.841
 6 2        3         0.841
 7 3        1         0.886
 8 3        2         0.909
 9 3        3         0.886
10 4        1         0.795
```